# Как высчитать номера в цикле?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Загружаю картинки из папки, `var folder = "assets/img/slider/";`

1 прокрутка слайдера = 3 блока, и из этих трёх мне нужно в средний блок добавлять 2 картинки (см скрин), как это можно высчитать гибко без хардкода?)
Сейчас тупо ручками пишу, что в средний блок добавляю `2-ю и 3-ю картинку`, далее нужно `6-ю и 7-ю` и т.д.

```
var imgCounter = 0;
```

```js
$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                imgCounter++;
                if (imgCounter == 2 ) {
                    $("#s02 .gallery").append( "<div class='img small'> \
                        <img src='"+ folder + val +"' width='399' height='307'>");
                }
                else if (imgCounter == 3 ){
                    $("#s02 .gallery .small:last").append("<img src='"+ folder + val +"' width='399' height='307'> </div>" );
                }
                else{
                    $("#s02 .gallery").append( "<div class='img'><img width='758' height='606' src='"+ folder + val +"'></div>" );
                }
            } 
        });
        initSlick ();
    }
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сравнивайте с 2 и 3 не сам индекс, а его остаток от деления нацело на 4.

Comment: а можно хоть мини примерчик?) а то не очень понимаю...

Comment: `counter % 4 === 0`

Comment: оО @Peter Samokhin спасибо большое, работает, мб напишите это как ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его?

Comment: @СергейКозин изучите базовые операторы и средства языка, странно что такая конструкция вам не знакома.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`оператор % (взятие остатка)`](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0).

В вашем примере: `counter % 4 === 0`.